# Array of floats to base64 ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, base64

I have one array of this kind, i need to encode this to base64, but they are floats so how can i do this?

```
part = [28.750438696879428, 26.65040665293327, 24.750377660791855, 23.750362401769962,
       23.550359349965674, 23.65036087586759, 23.65036087586759, 23.65036087586759,
       23.750362401769962, 24.35037155718328, 25.350386816205173]
```

Comment: Waht is the expected output?

Comment: Do you want something like this? `[part.pack('f*')].pack('m')`

Comment: Similar but i found that it's with 'G*', tks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array`'s `pack` method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Array.html#method-i-pack) in order to compose a binary string representation of your `Float` values:

```
part = [...]

binary_representation = part.pack 'G*'
```

You can then encode said binary representation in base 64:

```
require 'base64'
include Base64

base64_encoded = encode64 binary_representation
```

You can then transmit the encoded data. If you'd like to receive the same data back, you first have to decode it:

```
base64_decoded = decode64 base64_encoded
```

And then use [`String`'s `unpack` method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/String.html#method-i-unpack) in order to extract your `Float`s:

```
floats = base64_decoded.unpack 'G*'
```

The `G*` format specifies that the elements are to be interpreted as double-precision `Float`s in big-endian byte order when packing and unpacking. You can confirm that the data is the same:

```
parts == floats
```

[See it running](http://ideone.com/yfZRnl).